"Placement URL has wrong format." when excluding a placement via the API
I try to exclude a placement via code and I get this error (read bottom up):
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278214Z index: 251
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278211Z field_name: "operations"
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278208Z field_path_elements {
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278203Z location {
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278200Z }
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278197Z string_value: "mixnews.lv/news/2024/04/09/dich-na-pervom-svidanii-kakie-momenty-stali-navsegda-v-pamyati-devushek"
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278192Z trigger {
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278189Z message: "Placement URL has wrong format."
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278185Z }
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278181Z criterion_error: INVALID_FORMAT_FOR_PLACEMENT_URL
DEFAULT 2024-06-03T13:34:05.278177Z error_code {

How can I understand what's wrong in this format?

Criterions of type PlacementInfo can only have up to two path parts. See the documentation (section "PlacementInfo").
If you change the URL in your example to mixnews.lv/news/2024 the call should succeed.
